# Glimpse output not appearing on MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I have been through all the instructions and FAQ's regarding how to get glimpse to work.

I am however running MVC 4....

I have installed the Glimpse.MVC package as well as straight Glimpse.

It all configures just fine. I even added my own IP to the config.

On the client, under Chrome I can run Glimpse.AXD and it informs me that Glimpse is on.

In the associated "Config Settings: it shows:

```
•On = True
•Allowed IP's =
1.127.0.0.1
2.::1
3.192.168.97.180

•Allowed ContentType's = 
1.text/html
2.application/json

•Blacklisted Plugins = 

Under "Your Settings" it shows:

•IP = ::1
•glimpseState = On
```

I note that this last list shows an IPV6 address (::1) but I don't know if this is incorrect or how to change it if it is wrong.

So the first question is "what is the difference between "config settings" and "Your Settings"

Same result in IE 9.

Second and real question is: Why do I get no Glimpse output when everything seems to be configured properly?

Comment: Did you install Glimpse.MVC or Glimpse.MVC3?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have messed around with it for a while and I never see the glimpse icon. Then I created a fresh MVC 4 app, and did nothing but install glimpse.mvc3 and still nothing. If I turn on logging, I get a bunch of plugin binder warnings. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Opps, I just realized that my "fresh MVC 4 app", I had created with the empty template which didn't create _Layout.cshtml. So glimpse didn't have a HTML Head to inject it's script into. So my "fresh" app is working, however I still can't figure out why it won't work with my existing app. My existing app uses ninject, elmah and a bunch of other stuff, so it is probably some interaction between everthing that is killing glimpse.

Comment: Hey guys. Please take a look at the [latest version of Glimpse](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc3) (for MVC3) and these problems should be gone. Please feel free to report any issues to the [Glimpse Issue Tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues).

Answer (score 0):

[Support for MVC4 has recently been announced for Glimpse](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/03/19/glimpse-1-1-released-with-support-for-mvc-4/), you can [download it from NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc4/).

If you use the version linked to (1.1), you should have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem where glimpse wasn't appearing after installing through nuget.

In my case I forgot to enable glimpse for the first time after installing it.

To resolve this, goto `http://applicationpath/Glimpse.axd` and you will see a big button to enable glimpse which will just set cookie on the client. Refresh the screen and Glimpse appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking?

[image: Launch Glimpse in Popup]

*If you application is services only the GUI will not show.*